# Edit/Delete values in database using jsp

Tags: javascript

I have this table (result of a user's search) :

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <table id="Dest_table">
     <tr>
        <th>Check </th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>City</th> 
        <th>Url of Destination</th>
        <th>Category</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <%while(rs.next()){ %>
            <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
            <td> <%=rs.getString("COUNTRY") %></td>
            <td> <%=rs.getString("CITY") %> </td> 
            <td> <a href=<%=rs.getString("URL") %> >   
            <%=rs.getString("URL") %> </a>        
            </td>
    </tr>
         <% } %>
 </table>
```

and this function to delete a row on the table:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
 function deleteRow(Dest_table) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(Dest_table);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>
```

but beyond the row that i am deleting in the function , i need the same row to delete it on the database , but i dont know how... any help? and then need to edit them...

Comment: You write JSP in the title but tag it with javascript. Which one do you want to use to delete the row from the DB?

Comment: any code that can be  in jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Two options I think about:

1. Reload the page by submitting a form (automatically with JavaScript) that sends in a POST request something like "action=delete&id=blah". The jsp will delete the row with the specified id.
2. You can use Ajax to send a similar POST request to a servlet or a jsp page that will delete the row with the specified id. Then delete the row with JavaScript.

Comment: Use Google. If you run into any issues, update your question, comment and I'll post an answer